# Display Local Time in Browser Input, FormData Submit with ISO Format

Tags: javascript, datetime, input, form-data

I would like to build a form that displays the current local time by default, and submits a timezone aware time to the server on form submit. I can intercept the form data (as shown in my example) and convert the local time to an ISO time, but I would prefer to leave the Javascript out of the form submission (to keep complexity low) and just have the HTML form submit the ISO time.

Is there any standard HTML component that displays a local time, but has a timezone aware value without additional Javascript? To me, it feels like this should be the standard/ expected behavior of `<input type="datetime-local">` but it is not.

I understand I am only passing in HH:MM as the value to the `<input>`, perhaps I can pass in the entire ISO string, and then choose to display only the HH:MM with CSS? I haven't found a method to do so yet.

```js
var now = new Date(Date.now()),
  nowHHMM = now.toTimeString().slice(0, 5),
  inputTime = document.querySelector('#time'),
  submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit'),
  form = document.querySelector('form');

inputTime.value = nowHHMM;
submitButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // To keep form from actually submitting ...
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  for (const [key, value] of formData) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
})
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

form>* {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/save/" id="timeForm" method="post">
  <label for="time">Local Time: </label>
  <input id="time" type="time" name="time">

  <label for="submit">Save Time</label>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A common way to do this without JS is to have a hidden input that captures the user's timezone, so that when the form is submitted that is sent to the server as well and the server can then do what it wants with it. Otherwise, JS is the way to go. The common way to handle time is to store all values in UTC, that way you don't need to worry about timezones except when displaying back to the user

Comment: @MatthewHerbst—how does a hidden input capture the timezone without script?

Comment: @RobG - I don't mind scripting before the input is processed, I just don't want to intercept the form input before sending it to the server. I think MatthewHerbst's suggestion is to set the timezone to a named field input that gets sent to the server. I'm going to try later today, and if it works post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @MatthewHerbst comment on my question, I came up with the code below. There is still JS, but it happens not at form submit time, it happens at page load. This feels hacky, so I'm going to wait to accept the answer to see if anyone has any better ideas, but for now it will work with some server side logic to do what I want. It seems like there should be a better way to handle timezone aware datetime inputs in 2023, but perhaps this is the zeitgeist.

Also note, for anyone who is looking to use this code, if the user changes timezones without refreshing the page (unlikely, and not applicable to my use case. Maybe would happen if using an app while flying?) then the timezone will be stuck what it was when the page loaded. It's an edge case, but good to think about.

```js
var now = new Date(),
  nowHHMM = now.toTimeString().slice(0, 5),
  inputTime = document.querySelector('#time'),
  submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit'),
  timezoneInput = document.querySelector('#timezone'),
  form = document.querySelector('form');

timezoneInput.value = now.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
inputTime.value = nowHHMM;

submitButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault(); // To keep form from actually submitting ...
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  for (const [key, value] of formData) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
})
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

form>* {
  margin: 10px;
}

#timezone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="/save/" id="timeForm" method="post">
  <label for="time">Local Time: </label>
  <input id="time" type="time" name="time">

  <input id="timezone" name="hoursBehindGMT">

  <label for="submit">Save Time</label>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm not aware of a semantic HTML way to do this. My guess is because there are so many 3rd party libraries that can do this, and tons of examples, it's not important for them to solve, especially since any solution would have to be backwards compatible forever (few to no breaking changes in web). Really though, unless you truly need to store the user's timezone, just convert the value to UTC on the client on form submit, then your server doesn't need to worry about timezones. When displaying to the user you can just convert from UTC using plain JS.

Comment: The use of *Date.now* in `new Date(Date.now())` is entirely redundant. It will produce exactly the same result as `new Date()`. Also, *getTimezoneOffset* returns the current offset, it doesn't tell you the timezone.

Comment: @RobG thanks for the tip on new Date()! I'm an engineer, not a programmer, always enjoy getting more efficient. I don't care so much about the name of the timezone, I just want my dates stored as UTC, and displayed in local time (or the local time where they were generated), so offset works well for me. You did get me thinking about local time where recorded, vs local time where accessed with your comment though, thanks! (Event in one TZ, person accessing data in another).

Comment: The offset may not be the same all year round where daylight saving is observed, and places do occasionally change their standard offset. That's why IANA representative locations are used, as they can be used to determine the offset for any date and time for the location and associated region (timezone).

Comment: @RobG, if I store a date with an offset from UTC, on the date that it happens (Right now I would store Sun Apr 16 2023 13:38:59 GMT-0400 ), then doesn't that fully characterize the time I want? For instance, during the winter my TZ is GMT -500, but my DateTime with offset is unique and correct for a given value, or? I guess I'm not seeing the advantage of storing the IANA location (for my use case at least), as it would require another DB lookup vs. the DateTime and offset fully defining the time? Thanks for your time, sorry for the delay (missed the original notification).

Comment: A timestamp that includes the offset is OK, but there's a possibility in your form that the time is on one side of a DST boundary and *Date.now* is on the other side. A rare but difficult to find error. You should get the date, set it to the user selected time, then get the offset. Also, not all offsets are even multiples of hour, so `now.getTimezoneOffset()/60` may produce a fractional result (which may not be an issue, just thought I'd point it out). ;-)